# Bjarne Stroustrup chapter 10.5 example

Tags: c++, iostream

This is about an example in Section 10.5 of Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principles and Practices using C++" book. As far as I understand, it should prompt the user to enter the name of the file to be created (So I typed `probe.txt`), after that it should ask the user to open a file (So I type `probe.txt` again) and then the program skips my `while` statement and returns 0. How am I supposed to enter the hours and temperatures?

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>

struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter input file name: \n";
    string iname;
    cin >> iname;
    ifstream ist{iname};

    string oname;
    cout << "Please enter output file name: \n";
    cin >> oname;
    ofstream ost{oname};

    vector<Reading> temps;
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    while (ist >> hour >> temperature) {
        temps.push_back(Reading{hour,temperature});
    }

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to create the file beforehand (e.g with notepad) and type the data there. And don't write to the file you are reading from.

Comment: You don't enter the times and hours, it reads them from the file.

Comment: Ah, so it just writes the data from a file into a vector named temps in this example. So if I want the data printed out, I have to print it from the vector?

Comment: That is correct it is only processing files if you want to print you will have to change the example.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the prompt:

```
cout << "Please enter input file name: \n";
```

It is asking you what file you want to read the data from.

When you see the prompt:

```
cout << "Please enter output file name: \n";
```

It is asking you what file you want to write to.

Notice the difference in the key words **input** and **output**.

This loop:

```
while (ist >> hour >> temperature) {
            temps.push_back(Reading{hour,temperature});
```

Is saying that while ist (the input file stream) returns a good value (meaning it hasn't reached the end of file yet) we add an item of type Reading to the Vector called "temps". (A Vector is essentially a list container type) We created an item of type Reading from the two items we grabbed from the line in the file.

So to recap, we make a Reading from the text in the file, and then we add it to the vector called "temps"

">>" is an operator that reads the next item in the file.
In the code, it reads the next two items and puts them into hour and temperature.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining in detail. It looks like I was actually expecting a different behavior from the program. :) Now ot makes sense.